# Delegating to Local composer.json

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, composer-php, autoload

With my clean Laravel 5.3 installation, I can run `composer install` to install the dependent packages.

Now, I've an `internal package` with its own composer.json, like below:

```
{
    "name": "bar/foo",
    "description": "A package for handling foo",
    "licence": "MIT",
    "authors": [
    {
        "name": "A. Foo",
        "email": "a@foo.bar"
    }],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Foo\\Bar\\": "packages/foo/Bar/src"
        }
    }
}
```

So I prefer to autoload from the package itself, instead of autoloading from the main composer.json.

My questions:

1. Running `composer dumpa` from `packages/foo/Bar` doesn't take effect for autoloading. After `Generating autoload files`, Laravel doesn't know namespace `Foo\Bar`
2. Is there a way to run `composer dumpa` for all recursive composer.jsons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following section to your global composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/*/*"
    }
]
```

You also need to add the packages to the `require` object in composer.json